# Map Ctrl+RMB to MMB (Win10)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, mouse, remapping

My mouse's middle button stopped working, so I want to remap Ctrl+RMB to MMB (so I can e.g. rotate camera in some apps & games). I expected this to be an easy task, but it turned out to be not.
What I've tried so far:

1. Powertoys - doesn't support mapping mouse buttons
2. X-Mouse Button Contro - doesn't support using keyboard as input, or using Ctrl to switch layer

Are there any other ways to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script will map
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Right-click</kbd>
to
<kbd>Middle-click</kbd>:

```
^RButton::Send, {MButton}
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: Thank you! While waiting for answer, I found the AHK as well, and cooked this script:
^RButton::Send "{MButton down}"
^RButton Up::Send "{MButton up}"